# A beautiful battle is one you don't have to fight

Tags: meaning-in-context

While I was reading the novel "The Wheel of Time" by Robert Jordan (James Oliver Rigney), I found this sentence:

> A beautiful battle is one you don't have to fight.
>   (Matrim Cauthon, *Knife of Dreams*, Chapter 27: A Plain Wooden Box)

Does the sentence mean that: Never be in a fight? Or never start fight if you will lose it?

i think the comment by **oerkelens** is more accurate. Mat likes 3 things
Good ale, Women And gambling But battle cannot give him no one of that But the truth is that he's at winning battle dispute how delicate the situation So he's called son of battle, lord of battle, prince of raven, Lord of Luck,Marshal General,Son of Battles,Gambler, Lord Crimson, One-Eyed Fool, Battle Lord, Horn Sounder

Answer (score 5):

This sentence is a little confusing because of the way it is constructed.  If we split up the ideas, it becomes more clear:

> A beautiful battle is...
>
> ...[A battle] you do not have to fight.

Battles are often described as important, or bloody, or decisive.  A battle can be chaotic, or intense, or deafening.  The idea of a "beautiful" battle is odd, and sounds kind of like poetry.  The speaker is trying to convey something that he finds beautiful about battle. By using an unusual, poetic word he is telling us this is not an ordinary observation about battle.

A battle that you do not have to fight is an interesting phrase.  There is an important difference between a battle that you do not fight, and a battle you do not **have** to fight. A battle you do not have to fight is one that can be avoided by choice.

The speaker is saying that he loves a battle that can be avoided.  This character seems to prefer peace to violence.  He also seems to be resigned to violence often being unavoidable.

Comment: I came to the opposite conclusion: the speaker thinks a beautiful battle is a battle engaged in voluntarily (for the sake of battling).  Either is supported by "do not have to fight".  It's hard to tell without more context.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom - My first thought mirrored Mike's, but your interpretation is equally valid. There's not enough context to say for sure.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: Context from the novels indicates that Mike's interpretation is what is meant. The character is doing everything he can to avoid battles (he just happens to get in them and he just happens to be extremely good at winning them). As an author meaning your interpretation, I would opt for "a battle you chose to fight" to avoid confusion.

Comment: I have not read these books, but I've seen this or similar lines, and Mike's and Oerkelens' interpretation is the usual one.